# gets() function not working properly in C++

Tags: c++, gets

I wrote two programs with a common class and different main functions.

These are the codes:

**COMMON CLASS**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

class student
{
  char *name;
  int *marks,avg;
public:
  student()
   {
    int n,i,tot;
    tot=0;
    name=new char[40];
    cout<<"enter the name of the student";
    gets(name);
    cout<<"enter the number of subjects";
    cin>>n;
    marks=new int[n];
    cout<<"MARKS"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
        cout<<"enter the marks in subject:"<<i+1<<" ";
        cin>>*(marks+i);
        tot=tot+(*(marks+i));
     }
    avg=tot/n;
   }

    ~student()
    {
        delete[] marks;
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout<<endl<<"name of the student: "<<name<<endl;
        cout<<"the average of the student: "<<avg<<endl;
    }

};
```

**FIRST MAIN FUNCTION**

```
int main()
{
 int n,i;
 cout<<"enter the number of students";
 cin>>n;
 student *ob=new student[n];

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
    (ob+i)->display();
   }
 return 0;
}
```

**SECOND MAIN FUNCTION**

```
 int main()
 {
  student o;
  o.display();
  return 0;
 }
```

In the program with the first main function,the gets() function in the constructor of the class student is not working at all but with the second main function it is working fine.

Can somebody please help me to run the first program properly using gets().

Comment: Just the title concerns me... the `gets()` function *is* working properly; it's just your code that is not. (At least, unless you've come across some obscure bug that somehow nobody else in decades has found.)

Comment: `gets()` function never works properly. It always guarantees you a buffer overflow.

Comment: What have you done to try to debug your code?

Comment: Make `name` a `std::string` then `cin >> name;` or `std::getline` should do it. Much easier than dealing with the current approach (which I might add leaks memory).

Comment: getline() is a better alternative to gets()

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should avoid using `gets` as it is deprecated in C++11 (see Compatibility in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/).

The reason you see the observed behavior is due to the line

```
cin>>n;
```

When calling `cin` this way it waits until you have entered a complete line, and then parses as much as it can. In your case I expect that you enter someting like `10<Enter>`. The last enter will insert a newline (`\n`) character, which will not be consumed by `cin>>n`. The call to `gets()` inside the constructor will then (according to its specification) read up until the first newline character in the input, and then skip it.

Since the next character in the input stream is `\n` it will read an empty string, before you are are able to type anything else.

EDIT: Please note that you will have the same challenge if you replace `gets()` with `getline()`.